# Cannot retrieve CustomAttributes in Interceptor using DynamicProxy

Tags: .net, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm currently implementing Interceptors using Castle DynamicProxy. I require the interceptor to pick up some custom attributes on my service layer method, but invocation.Method.GetCustomAttributes returns nothing. Anything I could be doing wrong?

Intercepted Method:

```
 [Transaction()]
 [SecurityRole(AuthenticationRequired = false, Role = SystemRole.Unauthorised)]
 public virtual void LoginUser(out SystemUser userToLogin, string username)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Interceptor:

```
// Checks that a security attribute has been defined
foreach (SecurityRoleAttribute role in invocation.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SecurityRoleAttribute), true))
{
    if (!securityAttributeDefined)
        securityAttributeDefined = true;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(invocation.Method, typeof(SecurityRoleAttribute), true);
```

**Update:**

May be a configuration issue. The config code is as follows:

InterceptorsInstaller:

```
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
         container.Register(
            Component.For<LoggingInterceptor>()
            .Named("LoggingInterceptor"));

         container.Register(
            Component.For<SecurityInterceptor>()
            .Named("SecurityInterceptor"));

         container.Register(
            Component.For<ValidationInterceptor>()
            .Named("ValidationInterceptor"));
    }
```

ServiceInstaller:

```
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        string[] interceptors = {"LoggingInterceptor", "SecurityInterceptor"};

        container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<BaseService>().Pick()
                            .If(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs<LoginService>())
                            .Configure(c => c
                                               .LifeStyle.Transient
                                               .Interceptors(interceptors))
                            .WithService.DefaultInterface());
    }
```

I'm Using Castle 2.5.2/.Net 3.5.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Are you sure this method is intercepted? It's not declared as virtual, so it isn't going to be intercepted if you use `CreateClassProxy()`.

Comment: Ah, added that in. I'm able to debug the interceptor so can trace the rest of the intercept, but don't get any attributes back.  Registering with container like so:

container.Register(
                Component.For<IInterceptor>()
                .ImplementedBy<SecurityInterceptor>()
                .Named("SecurityInterceptor"));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it was because the proxy is an interface proxy.  Getting the method invocation target, then getting the attributes from methodInfo fixed it:

```
    MethodInfo methodInfo = invocation.MethodInvocationTarget; 
    if (methodInfo == null) { 
        methodInfo = invocation.Method; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your interceptor code is fine, but you're registering it wrong. What you wrote means “if I ask you for `IInterceptor`, give me `SecurityInterceptor`”. You want to say “intercept calls to the class that contains `LoginUser()` (let's call it `Foo`) using `SecurityInterceptor`”. Translated into C#, it looks like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<Foo>().Interceptors<SecurityInterceptor>());
container.Register(Component.For<SecurityInterceptor>().Named("SecurityInterceptor"));
```

Comment: Thanks svick, updated the config but no dice.  I've now included the configuration sections in my original post as it may still be a configuration issue.