# Autofac: How to force all methods of objects that inherit from a particular interface to have an attribute

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, custom-attributes

**Problem**
I am making a permission system in MVC .NET. I am trying to force all methods that inherit from IModel to have particular attributes, eg. Permission

For example,

```
  public class User : IModel
  { 
    [Permission(Admin, Moderator)
    public User GetUser(long userId){...}

    [Permission(Admin)
    public User DeleteUser(long userId){...}

    public User EditUser(long userId){...}
  }
```

Is there a way to force all public methods of User to have the Permission attribute? For example, the above code should fail at launch if EditUser does not have the Permission attribute.

**Possible Solution**

I was thinking of using Autofac (dependency injection) to do this job. However, I am not yet that familiar with .Net or Autofac. Any suggestions on how to go around doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I would write a unit test that uses reflection to verify existence of the attribute.

```
foreach(var method in typeof(User).GetMethods())
{
    var permissionAttributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PermissionAttribute)).Cast<PermissionAttribute>();
}
```

The above code may not compile - writing from memory ;-)

Also, you might want to google for `interceptor` if you want to intercept method call and check for permissions. DI will not help you.

Comment: thats interesting. Thanks. Could you give me a code example on how to write such unit test or direct me to any site that might help. 

The solution sounds neat, but to be on the extreme safe side (since we are talking about security), we could add dependency injection in addition to the unit test - for the extreme case that code is deployed with failing tests.

Comment: I like the interceptor Idea. You can use Autofac [http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DynamicProxy2] to intercept a method calls for particular interface, in your case it will be IModel. Somebody doing something like this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238012/cannot-retrieve-customattributes-in-interceptor-using-dynamicproxy].

Answer (score 1):

You would normally control authorization at the action level on your controller and not on the model. The MVC framework already has an Authorize attribute that supports roles.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

It is possible to place this attribute on the controller to enforce authorization for all actions.